# Custom an annotation view image direferents

Tags: ios

I have a custom class where I can add the variable "type" which distinguishes that type, this is the option to change the icon, but I have no idea where I can make that change icon, I have tried to do in the method mapView without getting an outcome
    import UIKit
       import CoreData
        import MapKit

```
    class MKAnnotationCostum: NSObject, MKAnnotation{

        var coordinate :  CLLocationCoordinate2D
        var title :  String?
        var subtitle :  String?
        var tipo:String?
        var image: UIImage?

        init ( coordinate :  CLLocationCoordinate2D , title :  String , subtitle :  String, tipo:String )  {
            self.coordinate = coordinate
            self.title = title
            self.subtitle = subtitle
            self.tipo = tipo
        }
    }
```

i want get a image direferent depending for tipo

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreData

class ThreeViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            //viewDidAppear(true)
            myMap.delegate =  self
        }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        let request =  NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PUNTO")
        if let results = try? context.executeFetchRequest(request) {
            for resultado in results {

                let latitud:CLLocationDegrees = Double(resultado.valueForKey("puntoLatitud") as! NSNumber)
                let longitud:CLLocationDegrees = Double(resultado.valueForKey("puntoLongitud") as! NSNumber)

                let lateDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
                let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

                let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(lateDelta, longDelta)
                let location:  CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitud,longitud)

                let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)


                myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                let pointAnnotation = MKAnnotationCostum(coordinate: location, title: resultado.valueForKey("puntoDireccion") as! String, subtitle: "Latitud: \(resultado.valueForKey("puntoLatitud")!), Longitud: \(resultado.valueForKey("puntoLongitud")!) ", tipo:resultado.valueForKey("clasId") as! String)

//                pointAnnotation.coordinate = location
//                pointAnnotation.title  =  String(resultado.valueForKey("puntoDireccion")!)
//                pointAnnotation.subtitle = String("Latitud: \(resultado.valueForKey("puntoLatitud")!), Longitud: \(resultado.valueForKey("puntoLongitud")!) ")

               print("color: \(pointAnnotation.tipo)")

                   myMap.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
                  //mapView(myMap, viewForAnnotation: pointAnnotation)
            }
        }
        myMap.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    func mapView(mapaView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation anotacion: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if !(anotacion is MKAnnotationCostum) {

            let reusarId = "anotacion"

            var anotacionView = mapaView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reusarId)
            if anotacionView == nil {
                anotacionView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: anotacion, reuseIdentifier: reusarId)

                anotacionView!.canShowCallout = true
                anotacionView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Amarillo"))
            }
            else {

                anotacionView!.annotation = anotacion
            }

            return anotacionView
        }

        let reusarId = "anotacion"

        var  anotacionView = mapaView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reusarId)
        let costum = anotacion as! MKAnnotationCostum
        if anotacionView == nil {
            anotacionView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: costum, reuseIdentifier: reusarId)
            //let costumView = anotacionView as! MKAnnotationCostum
            anotacionView!.image = UIImage(named:"Amarillo")
            anotacionView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "marca"))
            anotacionView!.canShowCallout = true

        }else {
            anotacionView!.annotation = anotacion
        }
        return anotacionView
    }
```

Comment: UIImage(named:"Amarillo") is set getting set??

Comment: yes, but all have the same image

Comment: I want to change depending on the "tipo"

Comment: Yeah its easy check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func mapView(mapaView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation anotacion: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if !(anotacion is MKAnnotationCostum) {

            let reusarId = "anotacion"

            var anotacionView = mapaView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reusarId)
            if anotacionView == nil {
                anotacionView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: anotacion, reuseIdentifier: reusarId)

                anotacionView!.canShowCallout = true
                anotacionView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Amarillo"))
            }
            else {

                anotacionView!.annotation = anotacion
            }

            return anotacionView
        }

        let reusarId = "anotacion"

        var  anotacionView = mapaView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reusarId)
        let costum = anotacion as! MKAnnotationCostum
        if anotacionView == nil {
            anotacionView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: costum, reuseIdentifier: reusarId)
            //let costumView = anotacionView as! MKAnnotationCostum
       if costum.tipo == "temp" {
       anotacionView!.image = UIImage(named:"someImage")
        } else {
            anotacionView!.image = UIImage(named:"Amarillo")
       }
            anotacionView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "marca"))
            anotacionView!.canShowCallout = true

        }else {
            anotacionView!.annotation = anotacion
        }
        return anotacionView
    }
```

Comment: Damn, your are genious!

Comment: echo.! (OK) excelente